# Netlogo, how to delete link between turtles based on value they own

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I am writing simulation where i am trying to simlate recruiting process for terrorost organization. In this model turtles have groups of friends i.e other turtles they are connected to with links. The model includes the forming of new bonds(links) with turtles they meet if their world view is similar and is supposed to have a mechanism for disconectiong from friends with world view most different from them among their friends.

Tried to solve the issue with following block of code which does not seem to work properly, often get the error message

```
"OF expected input to be a turtle agentset or turtle but got NOBODY instead."
```

related to value of friend_dif

```
   ask turtles with [(connections > 0) and (color = blue)][
      let friends_inverse ( 1 / connections )  
      if friends_inverse > random-float 1[
       let friend_dif abs([world_view] of self - [world_view] of one-of other link-neighbors)
       ask max-one-of links [friend_dif][
         die
       ]
   ]
set connections count link-neighbors
]
```

Below is the whole code for the mentioned simulation. The aim is to comparetwo strategies one where recriters focus on turtles with most radical world view, the second where they first targets the most central turtles in the net.

```
turtles-own [connections world_view]

to setup
 ca
 crt potential_recruits [setxy random-xcor random-ycor set color blue]

  ask turtles with [color = blue][
   let przypisania random max_start_recruits_connections
   ;; 0-0.4 non interested, 0.4-0.7 moderate, 0.7-0.9 symphatizing, >0.9      radical -  can be recrouted
    set world_view random-float 1

    if count my-links < 10 [
      repeat przypisania [
        create-link-with one-of other turtles with [(count link-neighbors < 10) and (color = blue)]
      ]
    ]
    show link-neighbors 
    set connections count link-neighbors
  ]

  crt recruiters [setxy random-xcor random-ycor set color orange]

    ask turtles with [color = orange][
    set world_view 1
    if strategy = "world view"[
      recruit_view
    ]
    if strategy = "most central"[
      recruit_central
    ]
  ]

  ;;show count links
  reset-ticks
  setup-plots
  update-plots

end

to go

  ;;creating new links with turtles they meet and movement which is random
    ask turtles [
    rt random-float 360
    fd 1
    if any? other turtles-here[
    let world_view1 [world_view] of one-of turtles-here
    let world_view2 [world_view] of one-of other turtles-here
    let connection_chance abs(world_view1 - world_view2)
      if connection_chance <= 0.2 [
        ;;show connection_chance
        create-links-with other turtles-here
      ]
    ]

    ;;show link-neighbors
    set connections count link-neighbors
  ]

    ;;how recruiting works in this model
    ask turtles with [world_view > 0.9][
      if count in-link-neighbors with [color = orange] > 0[
        set color orange
        set world_view 1
      ]
    ]

  ;; friend's influence on turtles
  ask turtles with [(count link-neighbors > 0) and (color = blue)][
    let friends_view (sum [world_view] of link-neighbors / count link-neighbors)
    let view_dev (friends_view - world_view)
    ;;show world_view show view_dev
    set world_view world_view + (view_dev / 2)
  ]

  ;; removing turtles from with most different opinion from our colleagues
  ask turtles with [(connections > 0) and (color = blue)][
    let friends_inverse ( 1 / connections )  
    if friends_inverse > random-float 1[
        let friend_dif abs([world_view] of self - [world_view] of one-of other link-neighbors)
        ask max-one-of links [friend_dif][
          die
        ]
    ]
    set connections count link-neighbors
  ]
  ;show count links
  tick
  update-plots

end

to recruit_view
    ask max-n-of start_recruiters_connections turtles with [ color = blue][world_view][
      repeat start_recruiters_connections[
        create-link-with one-of other turtles with [ color = orange]
      ]
   ]
    ask turtles with [color = orange][
      set connections count link-neighbors
    ]
end

to recruit_central
   ask max-n-of start_recruiters_connections turtles with [ color = blue][count my-links][
    repeat start_recruiters_connections[
      create-link-with one-of other turtles with [ color = orange]
    ]
   ]
    ask turtles with [color = orange][
      set connections count link-neighbors
    ]
end

to batch
  repeat 50 [
  go
  ]

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren't switching contexts (that is, whether the code is 'currently' in the perspective of a turtle or a link) correctly.

You start with `ask turtles` - pretend you are now the first turtle being asked. First a value is calculated and then compared to a random number - assume that the `if` is satisfied. The code is still in the turtle context, so the code inside the `[]` is applied to this first turtle.

The code creates a variable called friend_dif and assigns its value as the difference in worldviews between itself and one randomly selected network neighbours. In your code, you then have `max-one-of links [friend_dif]`. However, that only selects the `link` with the maximum value of friend_dif if (1) friend_dif is a `links-own` attribute and (2) the value of friend_dif has been `set` for all links. Neither is true. Furthermore, by asking for `max-one-of links [friend_dif]`, you are asking for the `link` with the highest value from all `links` in the model, not just the ones with the `turtle` of interest at one end.

So you need to get your `turtle` to calculate the difference for all its `link-neighbors` and then switch contexts to the `link` that connects the two turtles, before asking that `link` to `die`.

This is not tested. What it is supposed to do is identify the network neighbour that returns the biggest difference in worldview values and then use the name of the `link` (which is given by the two ends) to ask it to `die`.

```
ask turtles with [ count my-links > 0 and color = blue]
[ if random-float 1 < 1 / count my-links
  [ let bigdif max-one-of link-neighbours [abs ([worldview] - [worldview] of myself)
    ask link self bigdif [die]
  ]
]
```

Alternatively (and easier to read), you can create a `link` attribute that stores the value of the differences in worldviews (called dif below), then do something like:

```
ask links [ set dif abs ([worldview] of end1 - [worldview] of end2) ]
ask turtles with [ count my-links > 0 and color = blue]
[ if random-float 1 < 1 / count my-links
  [  ask max-one-of my-links [dif] [die]
  ]
]
```